# Search a user in the OU Active directory

Tags: php, active-directory

I need to make a Active directory search, for example I have the follow OU

```
OU=client,OU=office,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=local
```

How I can search a User (for example sAMAccountName='JUAN.PERZ') in the OU, using the `memberof` instruction?

I use php to make the search with ldap_search.

I just need is to search a user, if the user is in the OU, using php,

Thanks!!!

Comment: memberOf is related to Active Directory group memberships.  please be more clear as to what you're trying to accomplish.  also, how are you using ldap to query active directory?  adsiedit? vbscript? powershell?  something else?

Comment: Im using PHP ldap, I just need search a User by sAMAccountName, filter by the OU=client,OU=office,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you need is called ldap_search you can find a full sample [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-basic.php)

```
<?php 
// $ds is a valid connexion id (samAccountName) 
$dn = "OU=client,OU=office,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=local"; 
$filter="(&(objectCategory=person)(samAccountName=$ds))"; 
$justtheseattributes = array( "ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail"); 
$sr=ldap_search($ds, $dn, $filter, $justtheseattributes); 
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr); 
echo $info["count"]." found entries.\n"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is ldap_search:

**resource ldap_search ( resource $link_identifier , string $base_dn , string $filter [, array $attributes [, int $attrsonly [, int $sizelimit [, int $timelimit [, int $deref ]]]]] )**

first parameter is resource from ldap_connect, second is your ou in form

```
 "OU=client,OU=office,OU=Administration,DC=domain,DC=local"
```

third is filter in form

```
"sAMAccountName={$myADlogin}"
```

etc....

memberOf hold DN of group in LDAP, not an DN of OU!